# CSOM / REST : How can I get the _indirect_ groups for a user?

Tags: groups

We are using SharePoint groups to define roles in a custom application. One requirement is to get the groups which the current user is in.

I can of course use the *User.Groups* property but this only returns groups where the user is *directly assigned* to the group.

I would like to find the groups where the user is *indirectly assigned* to the group.

**Example**

I add "contoso\domain users" to the "Visitors" group.

If I then check *User.Groups* then the "Visitors" group is not returned.

Which query can I execute which *WILL* return that group? (along with all of the other groups the user is a member of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint will not give you that information. You will need to query the directory provider yourself.

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry is your salvation. Kirk has a post that can help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/07/04/querying-active-directory.aspx

Or, call Brett and get DeliverPoint. ;)

Comment: Ok, and I suppose it is the same for FBA roles?

Comment: One noddy solution ... create a Custom List with list item uniquely permissioned to each group then do an AssignedTo = [Me] query :D

Comment: Yup, if the group is managed outside of SharePoint, then you need to query that provider yourself. I do like your list solution, but probably a bunch of administrative overhead when groups are added/deleted...

Comment: We're managing group creation automatically in code anyway, so might be the easiest solution overall